# Namespace similar name confusion with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces

I'm bit confused at what rules I should be following. I found the problem arises because the current application name just so happens to be "Common" which is also the name of the "Common" company library. I have a WCF Service running and referencing a couple Class Libraries with the following namespaces:

- **WCF Service:** Common.Services
- **Appliation Domain Layer:** Common.Domain
- **Common Library:** CompanyName.Common

With this naming it compiles just fine, however when I consume the service with the WCF Test Client it says `Company.Common` does not contain `Domain` are you missing an assembly reference?

`Company.Common` indeed doesn't contain a nested `Domain` namespace. There is the separate `Common.Domain` but that shouldn't be nested so...?

If I consume the service in another client (a web application for instance) that already references the `CompanyName.Common` namespace it doesn't reuse the type because the namespaces are getting confused.

Using Visual Studio I can look into the two referenced assemblies on the client and they are showing the correct structure. From what I can tell it just seems that `WCF` doesn't like the namespaces.

I don't suppose anyone else has come across this?

Comment: Do you spell out all your type names? Maybe try prefixing them with `global::`.

Comment: Maybe its possible to override something in WCFProxyGenerator?

Answer (score 1):

WCF has a number of issues when it comes to conflicting namespaces and even classes if exposed as different web service endpoints. It would result in empty service Reference.cs file, for example. In any case, a general good recommendation is renaming the namespace into something with meaning, or breaking it down to many more meaningful namespaces, other than "Common".